# Corrupted transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, error

[In this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/0086601a26a823f9c407f7cf1beca1dba16ab152fb2a99186a9be5e16de4753b) There's a decoding error and an escrow. What could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decoding error is not really an error, per se, just an OP_RETURN. OP_RETURN is used for storing data in the blockchain and that's what this transaction is doing. It's not actually a spendable output, so the block explorer is getting confused and puts out a decoding error.